# How to do number-pad actions like: "Number-Pad ." to zoom into an object

Tags: osx

I use a Mac and the Blender emulator doesn't do those kind of actions, my computer doesn’t have a number-pad function and number lock doesn't perform any number-pad actions. What keys can a Mac user use to do number-pad actions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In User Preferences, under Input, there is an option to emulate the Numpad (makes regular numbers function as numpad numbers). You can then zoom using the regular <kbd>+</kbd> and <kbd>-</kbd> keys as well.

[image: Numbers]